# Edit individual chars in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, readonly, arrays

I'm learning about Cocoa/Objective-C, and I'm trying to be able to modify a `NSString` and edit individual chars in the string. I've managed to be able to change it to an array of chars, and change it back, but when I try to do `c[0] = 'b'`, it says, **"read-only variable is not assignable". I've included the .m file and .h file.**

This is the .m file:

```
import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize textField, myLabel;

-(IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender {
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello, %@!", [textField stringValue]];
    NSString *message2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ This part was added on afterwards.", message];
    const char *c = [message2 UTF8String];
    c[0] = 'b';
    NSString *output;
    output = [NSString stringWithCString:c encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    [myLabel setStringValue:output];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{

}

@end
```

This is the .h file:

```
@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *myLabel;

-(IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *changeButtonText;

@end
```

I'm assuming the .h file isn't relevant, but I though it'd include it.

Answer (score 0):

`NSString` is a container for an *immutable* string. Taken from [official reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html):

> The NSString class declares the programmatic interface for an object that manages **immutable** strings. An immutable string is a text string that is defined when it is created and subsequently **cannot be changed**.

Basically, by using just cocoa, you can generate new `NSString`s by replacing characters in existing strings, for example with:

```
- (NSString *)stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range withString:(NSString *)replacement
```

but you can't modify the same object. Exactly for this reason `UTF8String` returns a `const char*` which is an immutable pointer to a sequence of character. That's why you get the error.

You can use the provided NSString methods to generate new strings or copy the `const char*` C string to a `char*` (through, for example, `strdup`).

Answer (score 0):

c is a `const char*` -> its initialising value is its value throughout the whole runtime. Maybe you should erase the `const` keyword.

Comment: `UTF8String` message returns a `const char*`. Dropping the qualifier doesn't seem a good idea.

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked. I get warnings, but it works nonetheless.

Comment: @user2423270 - It may work but as Jack says this is not a good idea - you've been given a pointer to memory you should not alter, altering it is, shall we say, *unwise*.

Answer (score 0):

In Objective-C an `NSString` instance is not modifiable, for a modifiable string you need to `NSMutableString`. Alternatively you can create a new string from an old one. Unfortunately `NSMutableString`/`NSString` does not have the inverse of `characterAtIndex:`, to change a single character you need to use `stringByReplaceCharactersInRange:withString:`/`replaceCharactersInRange:withString:` where you supply a range - location & length - of the characters to change. Here is part of your code re-written to use these, first creating a *new* string:

```
NSString *message2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ This part was added on afterwards.", message];
NSString *output = [message2 stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1) withString:@"b"];
```

This first option creates a *new* string. Using a *modifiable* string:

```
NSMutableString *message2 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ This part was added on afterwards.", message];
[message2 replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0,1)
```

This second option *changes* the string referenced by `message2`.

Whether you create new strings or use a modifiable string will depend on how many changes you need to make and whether you need to keep the original string.